# How to make a queue with ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Have a problem making battleship game.
I created 2 panels with game decks for player and opponent.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpXwz.png)
When i click on opponents tile and miss i want programm to choose random tile on
player deck and make a move.

All opponents deck buttons placed inside List of button.
I use actionlistener for opponents deck
Program choose random tile on player deck

1. Action listener for amount of button placed on deck

```
public void buttonPress(){
        OpponentDeckGUI odGUI = new OpponentDeckGUI();
        PlayerDeckAggregator pda = new PlayerDeckAggregator();
        ArrayList<JButton> localList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(JButton button : odGUI.getOpponentCommonButtonList()){
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if(odGUI.getOpponentPinkButtonList().contains(button)){
                        button.setBackground(Color.PINK);
                    }else{
                        button.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                    }
                    localList.add(button);
                }
            });
            odGUI.getOpponentPinkButtonList().remove(button);
        }
    }
```

2. method that choose random tile on player deck and check if move was right

```
 public void randomChooser(){
        PlayerDeckCreationListener pdcl = new PlayerDeckCreationListener();
        PlayerDeckGUI pdGUI = new PlayerDeckGUI();
        int randomTile = (int) (Math.random()*pdGUI.getPlayerCommonButtonList().size());
        JButton localButton = pdGUI.getPlayerCommonButtonList().get(randomTile);
        if(pdcl.getPlayerDeckList().contains(localButton)){
            localButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
        else {
            localButton.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        }
        pdGUI.getPlayerCommonButtonList().remove(localButton);
    }
```

give me advise, how to make a queue work when i click button on opponents deck and get a response on player deck.

Comment: You wrote in your question: _how to make a queue work_ Are you referring to [java.util.Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html)? Have you searched the Internet for **java swing battleship game** to see how others have done it? I think maybe you need to use a [_Swing_] [timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: Sorry, i think i asked my question incorrectly. I found a couple examples, but havent found same realisation. 
I'll try to use a swing timer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution.
I placed method that starts when i click and dont get on opponents boat inside
actionPerformed part.

```
public void buttonListCreator(){
    OpponentDeckGUI odGUI = new OpponentDeckGUI();
    for(JButton button : odGUI.getOpponentCommonButtonList()){
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(odGUI.getOpponentPinkButtonList().contains(button)){
                    button.setBackground(Color.PINK);
                }
                else{
                    button.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                        PlayerDeckAggregator pda = new PlayerDeckAggregator();
                        pda.randomChooser();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So now, when i click on opponens deck and miss, i get
program turn to check tile on players deck.